# how can i store entier jtable in database n retrive it

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am building a billing application in java.  In my `JTable` may have *n* number of rows.  How can I compress it to database and then retrieve it from there?

For example, suppose there is a customer, `ABC`, and they have 100 items in this list or bill.  How can I put this 100 item and related column fields, i.e the full `JTable`, in a single column of the database?

I'm using MySQL.

```
JTable table = new JTable(row,column);
TableModel tm = table.getModel();
try
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);  
    oos.writeObject(table.getModel());  
    oos.flush();  
    oos.close();  
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  

    java.sql.Connection con=null;


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ankit","root","");
    java.sql.Statement stmt =con.createStatement();

    String maketable = "CREATE TABLE if not exists contacttable(Name Varchar(25),Position Varchar(20),Phone Varchar(20))";
    stmt.executeUpdate(maketable);

    System.out.print("table created ");
    //PreparedStatement pstmt = null; ;
    // pstmt.setBytes(1, b);
    PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO contacttable VALUES(?,?,?)");
    pstmt.setBytes(1, b);


    // . . .
```

Comment: The short answer, don't. Neither is this how databases work nor how serialisation is meant to be used. This approach could render your data useless in the future and incompatible across different instances of the application

Comment: then what should i do to save the the bill data n map it to the customer id

Comment: A normalized database should do the trick.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: You need another table probably called bills, which has a foreign key relation ship to the customer table (linked via the customer_id). Each row in the JTable would the be duplicated as a row in the bills table

Comment: suppose user made 20 different bills with 100 rows each in a bill .so should i make every customer table sparately ..wouldn't it will be huge on database

Comment: @ankit12 You need to do some research on databases and database design. The way you design your database will make a HUGE difference on how your app behaves and how well it can be maintained/upgraded.  Dan Bracuk recommended a book above; I suggest you look into that or a similar thing.

Comment: Storing data is what databases are designed to do! I agree with the other comments suggesting research into database design, before you go any further. @MadProgrammer has given you a good suggestion to get started with though...

Comment: i agree with the suggestions n but wat im try to say that suppose user make 20 differnt customers bill with of 100 items each per day ..then if i store this in bill table wouldnt my database will storing 20x100x30 rows in a month n this will affect my db ..so is there any alternative method to save such vast data ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a JTable in a database by reading it in a loop and then making up your SQL command, for example you can :

```
List<String> Columns = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
     Columns.Add(jTable.GetModel.getColumnName(i));
}
```

And

```
List<List<String>> Rows = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
    List<String> Temp = new ArrayList();
    for (int x = 0; x < jTable1.getColumnCount(); x++) {
        Rows.Add(jTable.GetModel.getValueAt(i,x));
     }
}
```

Then create your SQL Statement like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("INSERT INTO ")
for (String s: Rows) {
  sb.Append(s).append(", ");
}
// and so on.
```

Retrieval would be same but in reverse.

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the question, he asked for storing the whole jtable as a single record.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow: Sorry for misunderstanding of the question, but personally I don't believe that would be possible

Comment: jTable doesn't have a GetModel field, nor does StringBuilder and Append method, nor dos ArrayList have a Add method and you should be using prepared statements so as to avoid possible SQL injection issues

Comment: i agree with the suggestions n but wat im try to say that suppose user make 20 differnt customers bill with of 100 items each per day ..then if i store this in bill table wouldnt my database will storing 20x100x30 rows in a month n this will affect my db ..so is there any alternative method to save such vast data ??